# Convert single attribute class to attribute type

Tags: c++, casting

Can a class that contains only one attribute be converted into the type of the attribute?

This example prints `1` as intended. But is it guaranteed to work?

```
class A {
private:
    int x = 1;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << *((int*)&a) << endl; // (1)
    cout << *(int*)(((char*)&a)+offsetof(A, x)) << endl; // (2) //requires x to be public

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Or is there another way to access a.x without modifying A?

Comment: No, it´s not guaranteed. Alignment/Padding etc.etc.... But see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/

Comment: So this is better? `*(int*)(((char*)&a)+offsetof(A, x))`

Comment: Is the compiler allowed to optimize away `x` because its unused?

Comment: @Caraminel With offsetof, x isn´t unused anymore.

Comment: unfortunately offsetof requires the attribute to be public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be guaranteed (at least I found nothing in C++ specifications about it) but it is true that common compiler implementation put first element of a class or struct at first place, so that it has same address as the struct itself.

But you will get a *working case of a general Undefined Behaviour*. **Is it acceptable or not depends on your actual requirements**. Examples :

- this code will only run in a limited environment (your own machine or a few on which you have control) => you just have to document the fact and test for every change of compiler version
- the code will be included in a non sensible application that will only deployed in binary form => document it in red flashing font but you can contemplate using it
- this code will be included in an sensible application that will be deployed to many different systems => forget it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is implementing the corresponding cast operator :

```
class A
{
  private:
    int x = 1;
  public:
    operator int () const { return this->x; }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  std::cout << (int)a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Another solution can be the following. It's less intrusive in the code, but I prefer the previous one.

```
class A
{
  public:
      A(int x_) : x(x_) {}
  private:
    int x;
  friend class A_Caster;
};

class A_Caster
{
  private:
      const A& a;
    public:
      A_Caster(const A& a_) : a(a_) {}
      operator int () const { return this->a.x; }
};

int main()
{
  A a(10);
  std::cout << (int)A_Caster(a) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But if class A is a library class and can not be modified that does not work

Comment: It's quite dangerous to try to access to private elements of classes your not the owner. It's not a good practice !